# Yaml '=' key meaning

Tags: yaml

[Yaml reference page](http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html) mentions `=` key as `Default "value" mapping key.` but i cannot find any information about what does this key actually mean. Any ideas?

Also side question: why neither `<<` nor `=` are mentioned in [spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) when they are mentioned in reference page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<` is a [merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html).
`=` is a [value key](http://yaml.org/type/value.html).

Both are part of the [YAML type repository](http://www.yaml.org/type/) which is considered outdated by people active in the YAML community (since it is based on the outdated YAML 1.1). Support of them varies between YAML implementations; as they are not part of the spec, an implementation is not required to support them.

Comment: any idea why those keys are not part of 1.2 spec?

Comment: Because they are not a YAML core feature. Most people want them gone altogether.

Comment: Still i don't get why people want them gone. Both seem usefull

Comment: The comments are not the right place to discuss this. Feel free to join `#yaml` on freenode. (or the mailing list)

Comment: Ah, just `=: x` turns to be `x: x`. So easy. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Merge & value keys are very useful for complex data and when parsing into languages with good types.  Features are half the point of YAML over JSON.